# Portainer stack '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, portainer

I'm trying to add a stack to portainer, using a docker-compose in my repo that points to the following Dockerfile:

```
# Dev
FROM node:12.19.0-alpine3.9 AS development

ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN apk add --update python make g++\
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN npm install --only=development

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# Prod
FROM node:12.19.0-alpine3.9 as prod

ARG NODE_ENV=prod
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN apk add --update python make g++\
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN npm install --only=prod

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

But in the ubuntu server where is the portainer running in a docker container, I check the docker logs and I'm getting:

> http error: failed to deploy a stack: Building dev"
> level=info msg="Service 'dev' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1"

The `npm run build` runs `nest build` since it's a nestjs application.

When I run the docker compose locally it runs fine, no errors.
Is there a better way to find out what's happening?
any idea?
thanks in advance :)

Comment: That error message doesn't say much more than "it didn't work".  Usually there's some more details above that in the error; can you [edit] the question to include those details?  It'd also be helpful to see the `"scripts"` section of the `package.json` file and in general any more source code required for a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze just added the updates.